# Cannot hide title bar

Tags: java, android, titlebar

I am new for Android development and I want to hide title bar in my application.

I tried everything I can to hide the bar but the application either stopped or had nothing changed.

I ran the demo on a virtual device.It's a 5.4" FWVGA phone.
I've also tried to add
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
or
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar(.Fullscreen)"
but unfortunately , the application stopped.
Please tell me how to hide the title bar.
Here is my java codes , layout file , AndroidManifest.xml and styles.xml.

```
package com.activitytest2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //1.   getActionBar().hide();
    //2.   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.first_layout);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this,"You clicked button 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

}

layout.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 1"/>
</LinearLayout>

AndroidManifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.activitytest2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".FirstActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


styles.xml

<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
 </resources>
```

Comment: are you using AppCompat activity for that u need AppCompat theme. use this Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to simple way. just replace  `getActionBar().hide();`
 to `getSupportActionBar().hide();`

I hope this solution helps you.

```
"@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();       
    setContentView(R.layout.first_layout);"
```

Comment: first clear your project then run Build -> Clean Project.... it works smooth... i tryed it. dont change anything in your application theme.

Answer (score 1):

No need to add `getActionBar().hide();`

Just do this ,

> Flag for the "no title" feature, turning off the title at the top of
>   the screen.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

For test case , add this in your style section

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

and make sure below in **manifest**

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

### FYI

you can try with,

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
    //code that displays the content in full screen mode  
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: I've tried all of above and still nothing changed.Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AngusMurphy did you get another solution ?

Comment: The answer I have accepted works, though I don't know why. But thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in onCreate() will remove your title bar.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try with,

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

before the `setContentView`. like,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.first_layout);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AppCompat activity for that u need AppCompat theme. 
use this 
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

//add style file

```
<style name="Theme.SlamBook.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
```

//add in menifest

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SlamBook.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".FirstActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your style with below:This will hide your actionbar too.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For `AppCompat`, following solution worked for me:

Add new theme style with no action bar in your `styles.xml` and set `parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`.

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>

</style>
```

Now implement the same theme style to your splash screen activity in `androidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityName"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"> // apply splash them here 

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Here is result:

[image]